# Ext.Net: calling the direct method inside the ImageCommandColumn

Tags: c#, ext.net

Is there a way to call `SetTimeStamp` directly inside the `ImageCommandColumn`? I tried `App.direct.SetTimeStamp();` inside the `<Listeners><Command` handler but it didn't work .

Plus, is it possible to make a confirmation before raise direct event inside imagecommandcolum?

Thank you

```
[DirectMethod]
protected void SetTimeStamp(object sender,ImageCommandColumnDirectEvents e)
{
   X.MessageBox.Notify("asd", "asdsc");
}

<ext:ImageCommandColumn ID="ImageCommandColumn2" runat="server" Width="30" Sortable="false">
   <Commands>
      <ext:ImageCommand Icon="Decline" ToolTip-Text="Delete Plant" CommandName="delete">
      </ext:ImageCommand>
   </Commands>
   <Listeners>
      <Command Handler="this.up('gridpanel').store.removeAt(recordIndex);" />
   </Listeners>
</ext:ImageCommandColumn>
```

Comment: You are mixing DirectEvent and DirectMethod stuff. The method signature meets a DirectEvent, but you are trying to call as a DirectMethod. So, what actually do you need - a DirectMethod or a DirectEvent? These examples might be helpful to decide: http://examples.ext.net/#/Events/DirectMethods/Overview/ and http://examples.ext.net/#/Events/DirectEvents/Overview/

Comment: thank you daniil,I working so much on ext.net that I mix all concept,and notion.plus,there are so much example and different approches on yourweb side that, make me sometimes confused.